# Iterate through a map that is one level higher in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

Let's say I have some JSON like this:

```
{
'my_items': [{'property': '1'}, {'property': '2'}, {'property': '3'}],
'other_items': [{'other_property': 'a'}, {'other_property': 'b'}, {'other_property': 'c'}]
}
```

I want to iterate through the `my_items` first, then in each iteration of my_items, I want to iterate through `other_items`.

I thought it could be done like this:

```
{{#my_items}}
    <div>{{property}}</div>
    {{#../other_items}}
        <div>{{other_property}}</div>
    {{/../other_items}}
{{/my_items}}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/g9mgp/), what are you doing that different from that fiddle?

Comment: I've put my data in that fiddle and changed the variable names, and it works as I'd like. But I've copied the template directly from the fiddle and it doesn't render like the fiddle. It skips over the {{#../var}} loop. I'm guessing there's something with my environment. I'm using the latest version of Handlebars (1.0.0) and I've tried the version on jsfiddle (1.0.0-rc.3) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Oops, the variable I was passing to the template didn't have all the data I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, the variable I was passing to the template didn't have all the data I wanted.